# Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: qt

When working with the qt plugin, I get this error.

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1c20990) is not the object's thread (0x1b69ee0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1c20990)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/my_username/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried multiple variations of `sudo apt-get install libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-xtest0-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev`, but all those libraries are installed. How should I proceed?

Setting export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 also does not help, I get a long wall of errors along the lines of `QElfParser: '/home/my_username/anaconda3/bin/transformers-cli' is not an ELF object`